# Children's picture book about a father and son who travel to an alien planet that is actually a robotic hunting reserve

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Picture book short-story where father and son travel to an alien planet where the son is accosted by a series of increasingly strange creatures. The twist that all are robots. The planet is a hunting reserve where people use stun guns to stun the robots and simulate hunting. Book is 90s or older.

May have been part of an anthology of stories. All details are a little fuzzy and may not be 100% accurate.

Comment: This story might have been asked about  on Reddit’s what is that book. In the Reddit post, the poster says that the book was read out loud in the equivalent to 5th grade in 1989 and that the planet’s name might have been Isham. It may also be from an anthology according to a later comment from the same poster on Goodreads. The key similarity is that the animals are robots as part of the twist.